# Print a specific attribute from an object within an AJAX retrieved object list?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, ajax

I'm using an AJAX call to return a list of objects from a database in JSON format.
These are then displayed as part of an autocomplete text input.
The problem is that I want to output/display the NAME attribute of each object within the list.

```
$(function() {
    $("#ingredient-search").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url : "searchcontroller",
                type : "GET",
                data : {
                    term : request.term
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The actual AJAX & so on works fine. I'm just unsure how I can iterate through every element within 'data' and output the name attribute from each JSON object.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your json structure, try this.

```
$.each(data,function(key,val){
    console.log(val.name);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to loop through Json attributes :

```
for(var key in data.dates) {
     console.log('a = '+data[key]["a"]+', b = '+data[key]["b"]);
}
```

For example if the object is like :

```
data = [{"a":1,"b":"test b1"},{"a":2,"b":"test b2"},{"a":3,"b":"test b3"}];
```

Output will be :

```
a = 1, b = test b1
a = 2, b = test b2
a = 3, b = test b3
```

---

### Snippet

```js
var data = [{"a":1,"b":"test b1"},{"a":2,"b":"test b2"},{"a":3,"b":"test b3"}];

for(var key in data) {
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += 'a = '+data[key]["a"]+', b = '+data[key]["b"]+'<br>'; 
}
```

```html
<span id='result'></span>
```

If you have just one object and you want to get attributes names you can get them like following :

```
var data = {"a":1, "b":"test b", "c":"test c", "d":215, "e":"test e"}

for(var key in data) {
     console.log(key);
}
```

Output will be :

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the attributes of each object in your list you need like so:

```
var suggestions = $.map(data, function(record) {
   return {id:record['id'], name:record['name']};
});
```

You get an array of objects [{id:1, name:'Bob'}, {id:2, name:'Sam'}]

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has built-in functionality to do something exactly like this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

**Modified From The Docs**

```
$.getJSON( "searchcontroller", function( json ) {
   //where `json` is your JSON data
   console.log( "NAME from JSON Data: " + json.name );
 });
```

Essentially what this does is gets the JSON data from "test.json" or whatever source you like, and puts JSON data in an object that we can access with the variable name `json`.  You can get the name field by doing `json.name`.